# Xsl &#xA; for new line in transformation

Tags: c#, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I've this code :

```
<a>
   <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="$foo"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   bar
</a>
```

the probleme is after transformation I get :

```
<a href="&#xA;                PooValue        &#xA;"                 >bar</a>
```

My xsl:output is with indent="no".

Visual studio indent all the files. So put the code in one line work but

```
<a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="$foo"/></xsl:attribute>bar</a>
```

first is not very readable and VS will change me the indent so I want another solution.
kind of :

```
<xsl:attribute name="href" select="concat(mystuff)" />
```

but it doesn't exist and it is no very readable again.

Other solution may be :

```
<a href="{$foo}" >bar</a>
```

but and How can I use xsl treatment like below with this :

```
<a>
       <xsl:attribute name="href">
             <xsl:choose >
                 <xsl:when test="$atest">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$foo"/>
                 </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$foo2"/>
                 </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose >
       </xsl:attribute>
       bar
    </a>
```

Use :
`<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($foo)"/>` will have no effect cause :
 `&#xA;` is created between
 `<xsl:attribute name="href">` and `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($foo)"/>`

I work in `xslt 1.0` `C# .net 4` with `XslCompiledTransform`

More details :
  I put the result of my XslCompiledTransform in a

Comment: Please, provide a complete (but minimal) code example, so that people would be able to repro this. Otherwise you are telling me there is life on Mars...

Comment: I think the probleme is more a directive of transformation than a xslt syntaxe. So if I give my code (almost the same that above people) whill say me hey your code work! what's wrong with you. but I've really the pb

Comment: If this is the case, you are wasting your time and not only your time. How can I work on a solution to a problem if I am not given enough information in order to reproduce it? With the same success you may ask for help with ghosts haunting your place.

Comment: I don't want to wast your time neither the time of anyone in SO. I try just to explain my real problem quietly, Maybe someone who had the same will understand, I think for the moment Michael Kay is the closer of the answer but I have no xml:space="preserve", Thank you for helping me, If you really want I can give you a part of my code but I really don't want you waste time. Do you know if in XslCompiledTransform there is an option to set a global configuration for xml:space?  I repeat, I don't expect anyone in SO waste time for me but if there is any idea or recomendation it's welcome. Cheers

Comment: I see. @Christophe Debove: I don't believe there is any problem at all -- unless it can be reproduced. I challenge you to convince anyone this problem really happens -- the way to do it is to provide enough data so that at least one person can repro the problem.

Comment: @DImitre as I don't want any person suspect me to create false problem as you do I will delete my question.... So, I saw there is also in a comunity some extremist. Bye Thanks you to the people who try to help me.

Comment: I see. @Christophe Debove: The mere act of deleting the question means you admit there has been no problem... It is much better to provide enough data so that people can repro, then find solution. Isn't the main goal of SO after all exactly this? I hope you see that there is big area for improvement in your questions and I expect to see such improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if there's an xml:space attribute anywhere in the stylesheet. This would cause the whitespace in your xsl:attribute instruction to be treated as significant.

Comment: I will search but I don't beleive. However I think it's a good way of investigation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the inline evaluation syntax.

```
<a href="{$foo}" />
```

---

However, you appear to have a different problem.
The spaces and new lines you see come from the data source, not from the XSL template.

In which case you can use:

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($foo)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  bar
</a>
```

---

EDIT:

I can only reproduce this behaviour if I explicitly say:

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href" xml:space="preserve">
    <xsl:value-of select="$foo"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  bar
</a>
```

In which case, try

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href" xml:space="default">
    <xsl:value-of select="$foo"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  bar
</a>
```

Comment: and How can I use <xsl:if or <xsl:when with this?

Comment: @Christophe Provided you want to change the name of the attribute, or you want the attribute to appear conditionally, you can't. You'll have to use `<xsl:attribute>` then.

Comment: I don't want to change the name of the attribute but its value

Comment: @Christophe Then you can either put an expression into the `{}`, or clone the whole `<a>` thing into different branches of `<xsl:if>` with different values for `{}`. BTW, I can't reproduce your behaviour. The attribute gets created fine however I format the code. Are you sure the spaces and line breaks don't come from the source XML?

Comment: I'm sure for that cause it not value from node but from variable I guess there is an option a litle bit like xml:space because it seam have xml:space:preserve by default.

Comment: I can't use normalize-space($foo) cause &#xA; are created between <xsl:attribute name="href">
 and <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($foo)"/>

Comment: @Christophe Well, try adding `xml:space="default"` then.

Answer (score 0):

The whitespace(spaces and line breaks) inside the `<a>` are being seen as significant.

**If you want to ensure that the XSLT processor ignores that whitespace, put the text "bar" inside of an `xsl:text` element:**

```
<a>
   <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="'foo'"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:text>bar</xsl:text>
</a>
```

In this way, it is clear that the only text that you want included in your output is what is inside the `xsl:text`.

I get the following output from the above sample:

```
<a href="foo">bar</a>
```

Although it is a bit more verbose, putting the text that you want output inside of `xsl:text` helps ensure that only the text you want is included in the output, rather than sometimes random spaces and carriage returns being included, and you can feel free to format your XSLT without worrying about what spaces and line-breaks might get included.